# activate animation based on y axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

sorry this question is very beginner. I just dont know where to start i was hoping for some tip.

I need to start an animation once the user is at a certain section of the webpage. I was able to find the coordinate by doing this

```
$("body").click(function(event){
   alert("this is the x coordinate: "+event.pageX);
   alert("this is the y coordinate: "+event.pageY);

});
```

Can someone show me an example of what i can do so that when the user scrolls to the coordinate y 1254 that the animation begins?
I also found viewport.js but the documentation only shows one really horrible example

this is what i tried doing but it doesnt seem to work at all

```
$(".second-image:in-viewport").css({marginLeft:'-999px'}).animate(
        {marginLeft:'0px'}, {duration:2000});
```

I can not seem to use console.log with viewport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for a page scroll, then upon a scroll, check that you are so far from the top of the page or that an element is visible.

Try this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LVrch/
Shrink the result window so you have to scroll a bit.

Here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 200) {
        $(".second-image").animate({
            marginLeft: '230px'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you this makes some sense to me. I am just curious, what exactly is the 200? you say scrollTop() >=200 ....is this the position of...what? thank you very much again you save my life :)

Comment: 200 is the amount of pixels above the top of the window. So if you scroll down the page 200 pixels, that's when $(window).scrollTop() is equal to or greater than 200.

This may help a bit: http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/